# system str_replace

Tags: php, str-replace

I have the following string produced by `system("last")`.

```
user1 ftpd11967  89-23-224-162.d Fri Aug  3 01:42   still logged in
```

How can I use `str_replace` to replace...

```
still logged in
```

with...

```
<span style='color:green'>still logged in</span>
```

Tried

```
system("last", $rawOutput); 
$output = str_replace ( "still logged in" , "<span style='color:green'>still logged in</span>" ,$rawOutput );

echo $output;
```

I have also tried, besides system:

```
$rawOutput = shell_exec("last"); 
$output = str_replace( "still logged in" , "<span style='color:green'>still logged in</span>" ,$rawOutput );

echo $output;
```

Comment: Couldn't you just... try something?

Comment: well I did and it didn't work, was trying for whole day thats why i'm here now

Comment: Maybe you weren't clear enough. Post what you have tried, and what you expect. Otherwise this question seems... trivial.

Comment: i have tried all kinds of tips and tutorials, it was nothing related to system with str_replace, now we are getting somewhere. All tutorials etc. were almost same like this one that sephoy08 posted. But at the moment there is no affect, but i believe someone will try it on own site and will find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
// "user1 ftpd11967 89-23-224-162.d Fri Aug 3 01:42 still logged in"

system("last", $rawOutput); 
$output = str_replace ( "still logged in" , "<span style='color:green'>still logged in</span>" ,$rawOutput );

echo $output;
```

Comment: this will not work because i need to first use system("last"); and then from that output replace still logged in to the green still logged in

Comment: Then just do `$rawOutput = system("last");`.

Comment: system("last", $rawOutput);$output = str_replace ( "still logged in" , "<span style='color:green'>still logged in</span>" ,$rawOutput );echo $output; i have tried your way and also this way

Comment: yeah. i edit it above. hope it helps!

Comment: well it isn't working, it has to be on some other way, I don't know what are we doing wrong here :(

Comment: what is the value of `$rawOutput`?

Comment: same like before, same output like there was no changes made

Comment: strange, once you past the value to the variable, it should be independent.

Comment: all what it changes is ofcourse server last logins. Here is the output http://pastebin.com/NDPve7Pr still logged in is not colored, i have tried with <b> and it didn't work also

Comment: may i see your code? maybe your missing something.

Comment: echo "<pre><center>";

system("last", $rawOutput); 
$output = str_replace ( "still logged in" , "<span style='color:green'>still logged in</span>" ,$rawOutput );

echo $output;

 
echo "</pre></center>";

Comment: this should work fine... and the output of `$output`?

Comment: that is the output: http://pastebin.com/NDPve7Pr its the same like if i would use only `system("last");`

Comment: anyone else got an idea?